# Why type hinting based on method return type doesn't work in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I'm switching from Eclipse to PhpStorm and noticed that I won't get type hinting in this code:

```
class Bar{
    public function hintMe(){...}
}

class Foo{
    private $bars = array();

    /**
    * @return Bar
    */
    public function getBar($pos){
        $this->bars[$x] = new Bar();

        return $this->bars[$x];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

$bar = $foo->getBar(2);

$bar->__hint-should-appear__
```

In Eclipse when typing `$bar->` hinting will be active, but not in PhpStorm. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: Is your project index up to date? It should happen automatically, but your code above hints correctly in PhpStorm 3.0.2 here.

Comment: Also working here (3.0.2). Does CTRL+Spacebar show what you're looking for? If not, it would indicate an indexing problem.

Answer (score 4):

try it with spaces before the "*" like this

```
class Foo{
    /**
     * @var Bar[]
     */
    private $bars = array();

    /**
     * @param integer $pos
     * @return Bar
     */
    public function getBar($pos){
        $this->bars[$x] = new Bar();
        return $this->bars[$x];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

$bar = $foo->getBar(2);
```